# How can I add a custom classname to body on category page and all subcategories and posts of this page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just search for hours to find a solution for my problem. I need to add a body class to my category page and want to apply this class also on all subcategories and posts of the parent category.

For example i want category --> subcategory --> post to have the same class "orange" in body tag of HTML so i can style it properly.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you provide us an example page?

Comment: I don't have actually a example page that i can show you, because it is a commercial project. The thing is i just want to add a metabox field for category to add a custom class to the category to style all subcategories and posts on top of that category color sheme.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're putting in too much effort to get a class 'orange' when you can use one of the classes automatically provided to you.

A typical wordpress body class looks something like this

```
single single-listing postid-3259 custom-header header-image content-sidebar agentpress-pro-blue windows chrome override
```

There may be more or less but there is usually a class you can use to target a specific page ('postid-3259') or a group of pages ('single-listing').

Without seeing the page(s) you want to target I can't get more specific. Once you have your body class selected you can select any element on the page by adding more selectors.

If you're dead-set on adding an orange class this link may help.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/add-category-name-body_class/

Comment: Hi, thanks, but i think you misunderstood me. I need to add a custom class in the backend to apply on the color sheme. A color picker would also be nice.

For example:

In the WP Backend I want a custom metabox field so I can add in words a new class to this category like "blue" and this class will be on every subcategory and in every post with this top-level parent category.

My English is not so good. I hope you have now a better understanding of my problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you add this custom field in the WP backend?

Comment: Check out Advanced Custom Fields (http://advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, it rocked my world :) Thinks like adding a color picker in the back-end are very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the [body_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) filter and some [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to do this.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_parent_category_to_body_class' );
function add_parent_category_to_body_class( $classes ) {

    if ( !is_category() && !is_single() ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $categories = get_the_category(); 

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    if ($category->category_parent == 0 ) {
        $classes[] = $category->slug;
    } else {
        $parent = get_category($category->category_parent); 
        $classes[] = $parent->slug;
    }

    return $classes;
}
```